# MongoDB - How to exclude a record from a lookup query based on a field boolean value?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm doing a lookup query but would like to exclude records where the boolean field value within the lookup table is false, is this possible? Here's my current query:

```js
const pipeline = [
                {
                    '$lookup': {
                        'from': 'photos',
                        'localField': '_id',
                        'foreignField': 'postId',
                        'as': 'photoData'
                    }
                }, {
                    '$project': {
                        'createdAt': 1,
                        ...
                        'photoData': {
                            '$cond': {
                            'if': {
                                '$eq': [
                                    false, '$photoData.published'
                                ]
                            },
                            'then': '$$REMOVE',
                            'else': '$photoData'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
```

This is the photos collection

```
{
    id:'1234',
    url:'some.url.com',
    published:true
},
{
    id:'4567',
    url:'some.otherurl.com',
    published:false
},
```

I would like to exclude any records from the photos collection (photoData) lookup where 'published' is set to false. I think using 'project' would be the correct way to do this, but I'm not sure, and I can't seem to find the correct syntax/logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$lookup` returns an array, so '$photoData.published' will also be an array, and will therefore never match false.

You can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#-filter--aggregation-) to remove the unpublished images from the array like:

```
{$filter: {
  input: "$photoData",
  as: "photo",
  cond: {$ne:["$$photo.published",false]}
}}
``
```

Comment: Many thanks Joe. It worked perfectly once I'd worked out where to put it  , and it's also nice succinct code too, which is great. Have a great day

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$lookup` with pipeline to perform joining between collections with sub-queries:

1. Join `posts` (id) with `photo` (postId).
2. Match with `published: true` only.

```
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "photos",
      let: {
        postId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$postId",
                    "$$postId"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    true,
                    "$published"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        
      ],
      "as": "photoData"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "createdAt": 1,
      "photoData": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xx-SYxeUKrK)